# How to write a variadic Rust macro that forwards to the vec! macro?

Tags: rust, vector, macros, variadic

In Rust 2021, I have a struct type called `Intersection`, and I wish to store it in a variable length list, so probably a `Vec<Intersection>`. I can easily construct a new container with:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Intersection {
    t: f64,
    // ...
}

fn main () {
    
    let i0 = Intersection { t: 0.1 };
    let i1 = Intersection { t: 0.2 };
    
    let vs = vec!(i0, i1);
    
    for v in vs {
        println!("{:?}", v);
    }
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6a7b53df9b69037cd2eea3a53255e701)

This makes use of the `vec!` macro.

What I want to do now is abstract the container type a bit, to decouple the implementation (a `Vec<>`) from the user of the API. For now, and to do this in the least intrusive way, I could just use a type alias to encourage decoupling:

```
type Intersections = Vec<Implementation>;
```

To complement this, I would also want to define a helper function, to create such a collection from a variable number of `Intersection` objects. So something that would be used like this:

```
fn main () {

    let i0 = Intersection { t: 0.1 };
    let i1 = Intersection { t: 0.2 };
    let i2 = Intersection { t: 0.3 };

    let vs = intersections(i0, i1, i2);  // <--- what can this be?

    for v in vs {
        println!("{:?}", v);
    }
}
```

To put it another way, I'm looking to forward a variadic number of arguments to the function `intersections()` to the `vec!` macro. However I understand that Rust does not support variadic arguments, so I'd need to write a macro that invokes `vec!` internally, perhaps call it `intersections!(&i0, &i1, ...)`.

I've looked at the standard library's implementation of `vec!` and I'm not sure how I would forward the list of items to the `vec!` macro.

I appreciate that since I'm using a type alias so I could just call `vec!(...)` directly, however I want to decouple the interface from the Vector, so that if I ever change the container implementation, I can change the `intersections()` function or `intersections!` macro to suit the new implementation. This is a pretty common thing to do in C, C++, Haskell, etc, so that types can be redefined later.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply write a wrapper macro that forwards to the existing rules of the [`vec!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.vec.html) macro:

```
macro_rules! intersection {
    () => { vec![] };
    ($elem:expr; $n:expr) => { vec![$elem; $n] };
    ($($x:expr),+ $(,)?) => { vec![$($x),+] };
}
```

Then you can call your `intersection!` macro like this, for example:

```
let vs = intersection![i0, i1];
// requires Intersection to implement Clone
let vs = intersection![Intersection { t: 0.1} ; 2]; 
let vs: Intersections = intersection![];
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=08d03cdb2f50bd992171921d5b319f0f)

Comment: You can remove the first rule.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman yes, that would require us to convert `$($x:expr),+` in the last rule to `$($x:expr),*` though and subsequently the call to `vec!` in that rule to `vec![$($x),*]`. Otherwise we could not call `intersection!` without any values.

Answer (score 1):

You can just re-export `vec` as `intersections`

```rust
pub use std::vec as intersections;

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}",intersections!(1,2));
}
```